# VBA - Create worksheets and Insert Pictures automaticaly

Tags: excel, vba, image

I'm writing a code in VBA (Excel) that I select the path of one folder, and then I run the code, it list all images that I have in that folder, and then it start creating worksheets to insert that pictures (6 by worksheet) and then create more worksheets until all images on the folder was inserted there. The problem is. The code that I'm using is only allowing me to insert up to 50 images and create up to 9 worksheets. I'm looking to some update in this code to possibility add up to 1000 images, or 150 worksheets.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

See below the code that I'm using.

```vb
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim I As Integer
    
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(Range("E15"))
    
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Cells(I + 2, 13) = oFile.Name
        I = I + 1
    Next oFile
    
    ' copy
    
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Selection.copy
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("I15").Select
        
    'create worksheets
    '
    Dim P As Long
    Dim xNumber As Integer
    Dim xName As String
    Dim xActiveSheet As Worksheet
    Sheets("Report").Select
    Ce28 = Range("I28").Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Model").Visible = True
    Sheets("Model").Select
    Set xActiveSheet = ActiveSheet
    xNumber = Ce28
    For P = 1 To xNumber
        xName = ActiveSheet.Name
        ActiveSheet.copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xName)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "0" & P
    Next
    xActiveSheet.Activate
    
    Sheets("Model").Visible = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Insert Images
    '
    Sheets("Report").Select
    Dim CellValuep2 As String
    CellValuep2 = Range("P2").Value
    Dim CellValuep3 As String
    CellValuep3 = Range("P3").Value
    Dim CellValuep4 As String
    CellValuep4 = Range("P4").Value
    Dim CellValuep5 As String
    CellValuep5 = Range("P5").Value
    Dim CellValuep6 As String
    CellValuep6 = Range("P6").Value
    Dim CellValuep7 As String
    CellValuep7 = Range("P7").Value
    Dim CellValuep8 As String
    CellValuep8 = Range("P8").Value
    Dim CellValuep9 As String
    CellValuep9 = Range("P9").Value
    Dim CellValuep10 As String
    CellValuep10 = Range("P10").Value
    Dim CellValuep11 As String
    CellValuep11 = Range("P11").Value
    Dim CellValuep12 As String
    CellValuep12 = Range("P12").Value
    Dim CellValuep13 As String
    CellValuep13 = Range("P13").Value
    Dim CellValuep14 As String
    CellValuep14 = Range("P14").Value
    Dim CellValuep15 As String
    CellValuep15 = Range("P15").Value
    Dim CellValuep16 As String
    CellValuep16 = Range("P16").Value
    Dim CellValuep17 As String
    CellValuep17 = Range("P17").Value
    Dim CellValuep18 As String
    CellValuep18 = Range("P18").Value
    Dim CellValuep19 As String
    CellValuep19 = Range("P19").Value
    Dim CellValuep20 As String
    CellValuep20 = Range("P20").Value
    Dim CellValuep21 As String
    CellValuep21 = Range("P21").Value
    Dim CellValuep22 As String
    CellValuep22 = Range("P22").Value
    Dim CellValuep23 As String
    CellValuep23 = Range("P23").Value
    Dim CellValuep24 As String
    CellValuep24 = Range("P24").Value
    Dim CellValuep25 As String
    CellValuep25 = Range("P25").Value
    Dim CellValuep26 As String
    CellValuep26 = Range("P26").Value
    Dim CellValuep27 As String
    CellValuep27 = Range("P27").Value
    Dim CellValuep28 As String
    CellValuep28 = Range("P28").Value
    Dim CellValuep29 As String
    CellValuep29 = Range("P29").Value
    Dim CellValuep30 As String
    CellValuep30 = Range("P30").Value
    Dim CellValuep31 As String
    CellValuep31 = Range("P31").Value
    Dim CellValuep32 As String
    CellValuep32 = Range("P32").Value
    Dim CellValuep33 As String
    CellValuep33 = Range("P33").Value
    Dim CellValuep34 As String
    CellValuep34 = Range("P34").Value
    Dim CellValuep35 As String
    CellValuep35 = Range("P35").Value
    Dim CellValuep36 As String
    CellValuep36 = Range("P36").Value
    Dim CellValuep37 As String
    CellValuep37 = Range("P37").Value
    Dim CellValuep38 As String
    CellValuep38 = Range("P38").Value
    Dim CellValuep39 As String
    CellValuep39 = Range("P39").Value
    Dim CellValuep40 As String
    CellValuep40 = Range("P40").Value
    Dim CellValuep41 As String
    CellValuep41 = Range("P41").Value
    Dim CellValuep42 As String
    CellValuep42 = Range("P42").Value
    Dim CellValuep43 As String
    CellValuep43 = Range("P43").Value
    Dim CellValuep44 As String
    CellValuep44 = Range("P44").Value
    Dim CellValuep45 As String
    CellValuep45 = Range("P45").Value
    Dim CellValuep46 As String
    CellValuep46 = Range("P46").Value
    Dim CellValuep47 As String
    CellValuep47 = Range("P47").Value
    Dim CellValuep48 As String
    CellValuep48 = Range("P48").Value
    Dim CellValuep49 As String
    CellValuep49 = Range("P49").Value
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    
    
        Sheets("01").Select
        Range("B7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep2).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
    Range("D7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep3).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
    Range("B10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep4).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
    Range("D10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep5).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
    Range("B13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep6).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
    Range("D13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep7).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
        Range("B2").Select
    
    'PG2
    
    Sheets("02").Select
    Range("B7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep8).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
    Range("D7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep9).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
    Range("B10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep10).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
    Range("D10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep11).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
    Range("B13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep12).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
    Range("D13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CellValuep13).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 172.8
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 230
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 172
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 0
            Range("B2").Select
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use a loop for this

Comment: An array would probably be useful too

Comment: I'm looking to create a loop, but I'm trying to... Any idea. Thanks.